# Figuring out the kernel of a map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Im trying to solve the following task and i'm abit stumped:

> Let V be the vector space of functions which have derivatives of all
>   orders, and let D:V → V be the derivative. What is the kernel of the
>   map D−I(here I is the identity map)?

I'm was thinking,since the kernel is essentially the space of solutions which map to 0, the kernel would consist of the derivatives that map to zero(if that's possible),excluding 0 since its a constant and its identity map maps to 0.

However this seems too simple to be true,and i dont fully understand how derivatives work anyways.

Tips would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Can you think of a function whose derivative minus itself is $0?$

Comment: Like i said,i barely know what derivatives are. For some reason its in my linear algebra class even though we've never done any material on derivatives during high school or college. I'l try to find something online.

Comment: Do you know the derivative of $e^x?$

Comment: Just found it. Supposedly derivative of e^x = e^x,making it another exception for the kernel. Thank you,is there anything else to the task?

Comment: If you have no idea what a derivative is, this seems like an odd problem to be working on.  If your goal is to learn about linear algebra, I expect your source will have plenty of non-Calculus examples.

Comment: This was an exam question i messed up and brought me from an A to a B.  I want to not mess it up if it comes back to haunt me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of the map are those vectors mapped to the zero vector.  Thus, in your example the kernel of the map consists of those functions $f$ such that $(D-I)f = Df - f = f' - f = 0$.  Since the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, $e^x$ is in the kernel.  The kernel is a linear subspace, so any scalar multiple of $e^x$, say $Ae^x$, is also in the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for functions $y(x)$ that satisfy $y' = y$. This is a classic (and very simple) differential equation. It can be solved by separation of variables, but I prefer to think of it as a linear equation and solve with an integrating factor.

Expand, using product rule:
$$(e^{-x} y)' = e^{-x} y' - e^{-x} y.$$
Note that this is $0$ if and only if $y' = y$, hence we want functions $y$ satisfying
$$(e^{-x} y)' = 0 \iff e^{-x} y = C \iff y = Ce^x$$
for some constant $C$. This shows that
$$y' = y \iff y \in \operatorname{span}(e^x).$$
That is,
$$\operatorname{ker}(D - I) = \operatorname{span}(e^x).$$

Comment: $+1$ because your answer shows there is nothing in the kernel besides span($e^x$), and mine does not, though I think OP is learning linear algebra more than differential equations at this point